# error starting apache 2.4 with mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets

For reference I used this guide to setup integration between tomcat 7 and apache 2.4, with the mod_jk. https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ApachePlusTomcat_HowTo.html

When opening cmd in windows and doing a: c:\Apache24\bin> httpd -k start I get the follow error

httpd: Syntax error on line 526 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of C:/Apache24/conf/mod_jk.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_jk.so into server: access denied.

Below is the two files which has syntax errors.

mod_jk.config

> LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
>
> JkWorkersFile C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat
>   7.0/conf/workers.properties
>
> JkLogFile C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/logs
>
> JkLogLevel info
>
> JkOptions +ForwardkeySize +ForwardURICompat +ForwardDirectories
>
> JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
>
> JkMount /rehavoc ajp13 jkMount /rehavoc/* ajp13

httpd.config

> include C:/Apache24/conf/mod_jk.conf

Tomcat 7 is properly setup(I hope) Since I can in tomcat manager, deploy a war file with a test servlet running and see it work on the localhost/url.

Apache 2.4 should also be working seeing my web site is live and can be accessed on the web(just a simple hello world html).

Operating system is vista.

Also, have I understood correctly that with these three 'services' will I be able to deploy a war file into apache htdocs, including jsp/servlets and it will have no trouble running on my site?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it by not using apache 2.4 and mod_jk. Were better to just use tomcat 7 alone from the start.

Comment: Now that's not a solution !